# How to hide objects based on their name?

Tags: python, scripting

I need a super simple Blender addon that hides all objects based on if their name includes a certain string.

Basically a text box and a button.

So I could type in "collision", click the button, and if there are any objects, which have the string "collision" in their name, they get hidden.

Use case: large asset library in a single Blender file with separate collision meshes for most objects. For batch exporting everything has to be made visible, but after batch exporting, I wanna make the collision meshes hidden again.

Could someone code up a "hide by name" Blender addon for me? :)

Comment: Hi gulagkulak. Your question is off-topic here as we aren't here to produce code for you! See:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I can't find the function to hide objects.

Comment: @JohnEason im a bit confused on what is considered off-topic. is this only applicable to coding or also [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/301800/geometry-nodes-how-to-grow-a-perfect-honeycomb-structure-out-of-hexagons-one-by) where a similar job-like structured question is made?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I assumed from his question that gulagkulak was asking for someone to code a complete addon for him as he hadn't made any attempt to write one himself. The comments to the question that you link to are just suggesting ways to solve a problem which is fine.